# Not able to print JSON Response in HTML table properly using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json, html-table, getjson

I have written the following code for the printing the JSON in a HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/json",function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
      $("tr").append(field + " ");
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>market</th>
      <th>buy</th>
      <th>sell</th>
      <th>currency</th>
      <th>volume</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am able to print the JSON Response values, but was not able to properly print them in a table.

JSON Response format:

```
{
  "market": 1309480,
  "buy": 1309480,
  "sell": 1280017,
  "currency": "INR",
  "volume": 2253.4518854
}
```

Currently how the Table is looking:

[image]

Comment: Don't you need `td` inside the `tr`? Also you are appending them to the same place your headers are. You should make use of `thead` and `tbody`.

Comment: @N.Ivanov Can you elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var result = {
  "market": 1309480,
  "buy": 1309480,
  "sell": 1280017,
  "currency": "INR",
  "volume": 2253.4518854
};

//$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/json",function(result){
  $('#table').append('<tr/>');
  $.each(result, function(i, field){
    $('#table').find('tr:last').append('<td>' + field + '</td>');    
  });
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>market</th>
    <th>buy</th>
    <th>sell</th>
    <th>currency</th>
    <th>volume</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<div></div>
```

I just commented out the `AJAX` call, please uncomment & remove the result variable.

First append a `tr` to the table & then using `jQuery last` selector get the last appended `tr` & append the table to td data.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @shailaditya Thanks it worked for me. Just a quick ques, I want to insert a    one a static value like the first element of the row, how can I do that ?

Comment: @AlapanDas Similarly you can use `:first`

Answer (score 2):

You need `<td>` tag to display the content in the table.  `<th>` is a table header tag.

Try below:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/json",function(result){
        var tr = '<tr>';  //create tr tag 
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
            tr += '<td>' + field +'</td>';  //loop through the result and create <td>
        });
        tr += '</tr>';  //close tr tag
        $('#table').append(tr);  // append it to table
}
```

Also, I am pretty sure you might need this fro multiple columns (i.e if you result is multiple). You need to use 2 loops for that. Try it out. Created fiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/bipen/3prfj474/  ;)

Comment: can you help me with the HTML code as well. As I am not able to see any output, using the changes suggested by you.

Comment: @AlapanDas Wait, there was a syntax error. Updated the answer please check.

Comment: @AlapanDas Also, I think you want to display it in multiple columns if you result is an array. here is an example fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/bipen/3prfj474/

Comment: I am not able to get the output with the code you suggested. I have written the code here. Can you look into it once and let me know where am I making the mistake. https://jsfiddle.net/xt3pt6h2/

Comment: dude!!! `data` should be `result`. Here update the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/bipen/xt3pt6h2/2/ . Also, this will work if your result is `array` else the one above will work.

Answer (score 0):

You may insert tag `<td>` in

```
$("tr").append(field + " ");
```

like this:

```
$("tr").append("<td>" + field + "</td>");
```